# comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'd like to select the person's name and all their email addresses as a comma separated list. I know it has something to do with COALESCE, but I don't know how.  Here's what I have so far:

```
select PersonName,EmailAddresses
from dbo.Person
JOIN (
    SELECT PersonID,COALESCE(EmailAddress,', ','') AS EmailAddresses
    FROM dbo.Email
) Email
ON Email.PersonID = Person.PersonID
```

Right now, COALESCE is only returning 1 email address per person.
I wonder if I have to write a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving SQL Relationships as a comma delimited string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875979/retrieving-sql-relationships-as-a-comma-delimited-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select PersonName,

(
SELECT 
  EmailAddress + ','
FROM
  dbo.Email
WHERE
  Email.PersonID = Person.PersonID
ORDER BY
 EmailAddress
FOR XML PATH ('')
) as emailAddresses

from dbo.Person
```

The key is the FOR XML PATH('') - this groups the values together as a single string.

Comment: Note that this will leave a trailing comma on the end of your list - you could include some substring calls in there to remove it, if that's an issue.  Or just handle it on the code side.

Comment: Not only did that fix it, but I went running down hall showing all my coworkers how cool this was!

Comment: Yeah, it's a neat trick.  I was pretty pleased when I learned about it too.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
DECLARE @EmailAddress VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @EmailAddress = COALESCE(EmailAddress + ', ', '')
FROM dbo.Email
```

Comment: Right, but this returns a single variable.