# multiple row column values into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have multiple row with different column values sharing the same id . 
for e.g

```
col-A   col-B       col-C        col-D                  Col-E
1       12      2012-12-01   1900-12-01 2:00:00      1900-12-01 3:30:00
2       12      2012-12-02   1900-12-01 3:00:00      1900-12-01 4:O0:00
```

I would like to get in single row preferably with  separator ( * )

```
12  2012-12-01 2:00 - 3:30   *    2012-12-02 3:00 - 4:00
```

To avoid confusion - Edited the separator uses * instead of newline .

Comment: What are the data types of col-C D and E?  Date, DateTime or Varchar?

Comment: If this query is being called by application code such as .net, coldfusion, java, etc, it might be easier to run a very simple query that gets the data and use your application code to format it as you describe.

Comment: SQL is for manipulating data, not displaying it. Do that kind of stuff in the client code.

Answer (score 3):

It is a pain to eliminate the `[col-B]` on the second line.  The following formats the datetime's the way you seem to want them:

```
select [col-B],
       (convert(varchar(19), [col-C] + [col-d], 121) + ' - ' +
        right(convert(varchar(19), [col-E], 121), 8)
       ) col
from t
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, this sort of formatting is really not a database issue, but something for your application to handle.  That said, and with thanks to Gordon Linoff for the conversion:

```
declare @TimeRanges as Table
  ( [col-A] Int Identity, [col-B] Int, [col-C] Date, [col-D] DateTime, [col-E] DateTime );

insert into @TimeRanges ( [col-B], [col-C], [col-D], [col-E] ) values
  ( 12, '20121201', '19001201 02:00:00', '19001201 03:30:00' ),
  ( 12, '20121202', '19001201 03:00:00', '19001201 04:00:00' ),
  ( 13, '20121219', '19001201 09:00:00', '19001201 17:00:00' );

select * from @TimeRanges;

select [col-A],
  case when RN = 1 then Cast( [col-B] as VarChar(10) ) else '' end as [col-B], Range
  from (
    select [col-B], Row_Number() over ( partition by [col-B] order by [col-A] ) as RN,
      ( Convert( VarChar(19), [col-C] + [col-D], 121 ) + ' - ' +
        Right( Convert( VarChar(19), [col-E], 121 ), 8 ) )  as Range
      from @TimeRanges ) as ArbitraryPlaceholder
  order by [col-A];
```

Comment: @KevinPieterson - Do you want to align the columns with tabs or spaces?  This _really_ doesn't belong in the database.  You can use the technique shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811577/summarize-the-list-into-a-comma-separated-string) to combine rows into a single string and substitute a newline instead of a comma.  And add tabs.