# Concatenating a single column into a single row in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to compile a list of dumpsters at a given location that a driver needs to pick up. I have a table like this:

```
Stop Number   Dumpster Number
------------------------------------    
    1              245
    1              248
    2              312
    2              314
    2              316
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Stop Number    Dumpster Number
-------------------------------
    1          245  248
    2          312  314  316
```

The code I built is below, but I am getting the same result as the first table, with just the spaces on the end.

```
SELECT 
    [StopNumber], 
    CAST((CONCAT([ContainerID],'  '))AS VARCHAR) AS ContainersAtStop
FROM 
    [TripSchedule]
GROUP BY 
    StopNumber, (CONCAT([ContainerID],'  '))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([StopNumber] INT, [DumpsterNumber] VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
(1,'245'),
(1,'248'),
(2,'312'),
(2,'314'),
(2,'316')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t.[StopNumber] 
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [DumpsterNumber]
              FROM TestTableOne
              WHERE [StopNumber] = t.StopNumber
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS [DumpsterNumber]
FROM TestTableOne t
GROUP BY t.[StopNumber]
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════════╦════════════════╗
║ StopNumber ║ DumpsterNumber ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╣
║          1 ║ 245, 248       ║
║          2 ║ 312, 314, 316  ║
╚════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: God I love my ASCII Tables :)

Comment: I thought about a cross apply, but decided to go with a correlated sub query.  A conflicted mind ...

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA They will be the same I think. But have a look at the discussion of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9811631/569436). It is way better to use a group by clause than to use distinct. BTW, the ASCII Tables looks awful on a phone :).

Comment: Yea I have just checked the execution plan for both queries and they are exactly the same. and sorry about the inconvenience that my ascii table may have caused you @MikaelEriksson

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out @MikaelEriksson very informative link as well thanks pal

Comment: Your welcome and don't worry about my inconvenience. Here is a piece of code that will show you the benefit of using group by http://pastebin.com/JZHhjReG Using large groups that give few rows back is where group by really outperforms the distinct versions.

Comment: Good point Mikael.  When N becomes large, we have to reduce by looking at all those large strings.  If we group by, we only have two choices for Stop Number.

Comment: I am having a little trouble understanding the syntax and functions at work in this code. Is there some place that discusses these in depth?
P.S. I used this code and am able to pull the list the way I like, but I am still having trouble with the grouping side of it. I am getting every value for every stop and that is obviously not right. I had to add a where clause in the subquery so I am thinking that might have thrown something off.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA Is there a way to separate these into a dynamic number of columns? I am having similar issue with some different tables, and only a little bit difference in the desired layout. When I get them to the same line, I just need them in separate columns. Still having trouble understanding the syntax.

Comment: Hi Jake, the problem with your solution is how many columns?  Lets say you never have more than 25 columns.  What happens when you have data with twenty six columns?  XML gets around this problem.  However, I did see a post with a person having issues with > 64 columns in XML.  Again, I stay away from cursors, but a SELECT DISTINCT list of stop numbers as a driver in the outer loop and a PIVOT in the inner loop with a ROW_NUMBER() for column name might be one solution.  A power shell script might actually run faster.  Sounds like a future blog article!  If you still have issues, email me.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA lets see how crafty you are :) could you please have a look [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545133/creating-users-on-secondary-server-in-log-shipping) and suggest something :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a correlated sub query as an expression.  Take the distinct value of the results.  I create a simple test table in tempdb below.

[image]

```
-- Just playing
use tempdb
go

-- Remove table 
if object_id('d1') > 0
drop table d1
go

-- Create table
create table d1
(
stop_num int,
dumpster_num varchar(6)
);
go

-- Add data
insert into d1
values
(1, '245'),
(1, '248'),
(2, '312'),
(2, '314'),
(2, '316');
go

-- Sub-query to get list
select 
  stop_num, 
  stuff((
    SELECT ISNULL(dumpster_num,'') + ','
    FROM d1 as inner1
    WHERE inner1.stop_num = outer1.stop_num
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 2, '') as list
from d1 as outer1
group by stop_num
```

**So the question is which one is faster, the cross apply or the sub-query?**

```
-- Show time & i/o
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON
GO

-- Remove clean buffers & clear plan cache
CHECKPOINT 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
```

I ran the following above to turn on time and stats.  Also, I cleared out buffers and query cache.  Allow a 10 seconds or so for these commands to complete before taking a reading.

I changed the code below to use table d1 (dumpster) table in tempdb.  Compare apples to apples.

```
-- Use a static table in tempdb
SELECT  
    stop_num, 
    STUFF(list.nums, 1 , 2,'') AS dumpster_num
FROM d1 t CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT ', ' + CAST(dumpster_num AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM d1
        WHERE stop_num = t.stop_num
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) list(nums)
GROUP BY stop_num
```

I did get some variance between runs, but taking the best numbers after a buffer/cache clear, the run time is the same.  The compile time is a little different.  The I/O is exact.

```
--
-- Cross apply (numbers)
-- 

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 21 ms.
(2 row(s) affected)

Table 'd1'. 
Scan count 6, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, 
read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, 
lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 14 ms.


--
-- sub query (numbers)
-- 

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 26 ms.

(2 row(s) affected)
Table 'd1'. Scan count 6, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, 
read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 14 ms.
```

I would say, both TSQL statements perform almost the same.