# Select identical values once in column and owned values in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I know title donesn't make sense at first. Let me explain  .

Got 3 tables : Reefers, Discipline and JudgedBy

In Reefer table i got ID, Name and Surname.

```
---------------
1  John   Doe
2  john2  Doe2
3  etc
```

In Discipline table i got Discipline name, and id

```
------------
1   hockey
2   Basketball
3   football
4   etc
```

In JudgedBy table i got foreign keys from discipline and Reefer table. There is Reefer id and discipline id . In one sport discipline there can be multiple reefers

```
---------------
1  4  //Discipline with id 1 is judged by reefer with id 4,2,3 
1  2
1  3
```

What i want is, select disciplines (name) in one column and reefers in other column, so that discipline shows only once and all reefers show in row as string. Something like this

```
---------
|hockey|      |John Doe , John2 Doe2, etc| 
|Basketball|  |Another reefer, Jet another reefer|
```

So far i have achieved both pieces of this task, but i cant put them together.

For selecting disciplines and reefers i use inner join

```
SELECT  Discipline.Name, Reefers.name, Reefers.surname
FROM  Discipline INNER JOIN
      JudgedBy ON JudgedBy.Discipline_ID = Discipline.ID INNER JOIN
      Reefers ON JudgedBy.Reefer_ID = Reefers.ID
```

I get

```
------------
hockey   John Doe
hockey   John2 Doe2
hockey   Another one
```

Other part is to put them in one string. Found this piece

```
declare @out as varchar(max)
set @out= ''
select @out = @out + Name + ' ' + Surnam + ', ' from Reefers
select @out as Game reefers
```

How i can put these both pieces together? I hope i explain what i want to achieve.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating a single column into a single row in SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912675/concatenating-a-single-column-into-a-single-row-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing aggregate string concatenation in SQL Server is a bit of a pain.  It requires a subquery and `for xml path()`.

Here is an example for what you want to do:

```
select d.name,
       stuff((select ', '+r.name + ' ' + r.surname
              from JudgedBy jb join
                   Reefers r
                   on jb.Reefer_ID = r.ID
              where jb.Discipline_ID = d.ID
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 2, '')
from Discipline d;
```