# How to Get Comma Seperated data from Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have Two Table something like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bQu0.png) image.

I Need Comma Separated data like that of in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jceDD.png).

Comment: there is STRING_SPLIT function introduced in SQL Serrver 2016..Finally !

Comment: I so wish there was option to close a question sighting `Not enough efforts to find solution`.

Comment: can u check m answer .@krishna prajpati

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summarize the list into a comma-separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811577/summarize-the-list-into-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct t.[name],
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t1.notification
         from yourtable t1
         where t.[id] = t1.[id]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') notification
from yourtable t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id , Name ,
 STUFF ( ( SELECT ',' + Noti FROM Your_table T1 WHERE T1.Id = T2.Id FOR XML PATH('') ) ,1,1,'') 
FROM Your_table T2 GROUP BY id ,Name
```

Comment: i think its only group by id