# Concatenation of integers with commas in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I often find that I execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Is there a function which can concatenate a resultset which returns integers with commas?

For example

`concatenate(SELECT ID FROM TABLE)` would return `1,2,3,4`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving SQL Relationships as a comma delimited string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875979/retrieving-sql-relationships-as-a-comma-delimited-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do the trick... I would think this would be much more efficient to do in an application layer but there are times (reporting) when you end up resorting to these types of tricks.

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + cast(ID as varchar(10))
FROM table
SELECT @listStr
```

I learned this trick from Pinal Dave see: [Create a Comma Delimited List Using SELECT Clause From Table Column](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/04/sql-server-create-a-comma-delimited-list-using-select-clause-from-table-column/)

Answer (score 2):

I won't pretend to know exactly what you're doing with the result, but if you're going to be running dynamic SQL (or manual SQL) with this result, then why not just use the query that returns these IDs as the subquery for an `IN` or `EXISTS`?  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE ...)
```